# How to calculate a square polygon with a specific center?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, geospatial, geo, spatial-query

I have WGS 84 coordinates of a point and I need to create a "square" polygon with its center at the above point. Vertices defined as follows:

```
       a    N    a
W *---------+---------* E
            |
            |a
            |
            X
            |
            |a
            |
W *---------+---------* E
       a    S    a
```

`X` is the starting point and `a` is a given distance in metres.

1. As point coordinates are stored in BigQuery along with other geography, it is preferable to calculate these polygons in the query. Can I generate them using BigQuery's [geography functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions)? (I did not find a way to calculate coordinates of a point X metres to N/E/S/W from the starting point).
2. If #1 is not possible, what Python libraries and methods can I use to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not quite a square, due to spherical distortion the distance between two top corners will be shorter than `2a` and differ from distance between two bottom corners, and differ from distance between side corners. But if `a` is small enough, it is close enough to a square, and with reasonable error margin you can do it. I think the simplest way to do it in BigQuery and avoid explicit trigonometry is to take a small offset, measure distance, and take proportionally larger offset:

```
-- computes distance in degrees along parallel at specified latitude
create temp function _to_lng_degrees(lat FLOAT64, a FLOAT64) AS
(
    a / ST_Distance(ST_GeogPoint(0, lat), ST_GeogPoint(1, lat))
);

-- computes distance in degrees along meridian
create temp function _to_lat_degrees(a FLOAT64) AS
(
    a / ST_Distance(ST_GeogPoint(0, 0), ST_GeogPoint(0, 1))
);

create temp function rect(point GEOGRAPHY, a FLOAT64) AS
((
    SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(
        [ST_GeogPoint(x - dx, y - dy), ST_GeogPoint(x + dx, y - dy),
         ST_GeogPoint(x + dx, y + dy), ST_GeogPoint(x - dx, y + dy),
         ST_GeogPoint(x - dx, y - dy)]))
    FROM (
      SELECT ST_X(point) x, _to_lng_degrees(ST_Y(point), a) dx, 
             ST_Y(point) y, _to_lat_degrees(a) dy)
));

select rect(ST_GeogPoint(-122.1555771, 47.6858382), 1000)
```

Comment: Oh, that is smart. I did it by manually calculating meter-to-degree ratio, but now I see how I could calculate it using `ST_Distance()`. BTW, `_to_lat_degrees()` seems to be constant.